# Story from the 40s or 50s with a loft full of boulder like life forms

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A guy’s loft is inhabited by hulking giant boulder like objects. He eventually learns they are life forms with an extremely slow almost glacial metabolism. They move only an inch or two in a year.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: This sounds like an interesting story, try to fill in some more detail and you’ll get better results.